# Sharepoint Requesting Access to ressource

Tags: sharepoint, azure-active-directory

I have an issue here with an user who has taken over the email of an old employee.

aa@domain.com

When searching for the user in sharepoint the correct name shows up
"Alex Alexen"
When looking at the user data either in azure active directory,graph api or delve
it all shows up as
"Alex Alexen"

However, if "Alex Alexen" tries to access a site he does not have access to "request access", the request shows up as
"Ali Alison" has requested access to X.
"Accept/Deny"

Is there somewhere else on sharepoint where user data is store?
Many years have

Years have passen from Ali to Alex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

•   In sharepoint online, the items are retained for a period of 93 days from the time you delete them from their original location. They stay in the site recycle bin for the time until the bin is emptied, or the items are deleted from there. After that, these items are permanently deleted from the sharepoint database.

•   Check if you are using directory synchronization, if yes, then the user has to be deleted from the on premises active directory first and then from Microsoft 365 admin center. After you delete a user, a series of jobs will remove the user from sharepoint. After the next incremental profile import job, the user (or users) will be marked as deleted, the user's profile page will be deleted, and the user's OneDrive will be marked for deletion by the MySite cleanup job.

•   To delete a user from Microsoft 365 admin center, you will have to login as a global administrator and delete the user from there. Also, you can try clearing the browser cache and history of the browser from which you are accessing the sharepoint site.

Even after deleting a user from Microsoft 365, if the user still appears in people searches, you will have to delete it from user info list. To do this, please refer the steps below: -

•   Browse to each site collection that the user had access to and visited the site, then add the ‘/_layouts/15/people.aspx?MembershipGroupId=0’ string to the site collection URL as a suffix and access it. Ex.: - ‘https://abc.manage.com/_layouts/15/people.aspx?MembershipGroupId’

•   Once opened, select the person from the list, then on the ‘Actions’ menu, select ‘Delete users from site collection’.

Please refer the below links for more information: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/compliance/assurance/assurance-sharepoint-online-data-deletion

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/remove-users

Thanking you,